# Controls size are different at Runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize

I noticed the groupbox label is different at runtime, I tried some properties like anchor or autosize but it doesn't seems to work.
[Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTyc.png)

How can I try?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I don't know if this is a workaround or the solution but I realized that Flatstyle property needs to be set to System. This way you can also center the text of groupbox.